# register_post_type & 'register_meta_box_cb' argument

Tags: custom-post-types

I just tried the first time to extend a custom post type admin-UI-edit-page with some "meta" boxes (if this is the right word).

```
register_post_type( 'post_type', array(
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'additional_input_field'
) );

function additional_input_field()
{
    global $post;

    $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $length = $custom["post_type-length"][0];

    return print '<label>Length:</label><input name="post_type-length" value="'.$length.'" />';
}
```

So far i haven't seen any documentation or example about how to use this. A look in the core showed me that it should be equal to:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes'.$post_type, 'additional_input_field', 10, 1 );
```

The appropriate hook can be found in (core) `~/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` line #163. The call for add_action in (core) `~/wp-includes/post.php` line #877. The only problem is that it doesn't seem to work as expected. The field get's loaded in front (visually: on top) of everything else. If I try to hook it directly to `'add_meta_boxes'.$post_type`, I get nothing.

*Simplified examples in this text to show what i mean. Typos may be there but doesn't matter. The callback fn is taken from some sample code over [here](http://kovshenin.com/archives/extending-custom-post-types-in-wordpress-3-0/).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love answering my own questions: Wrap the function `add_additional_input_field()` in a new function that contains [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and call it in the `register_meta_box_cb` argument.

And yes: This is the solution.

**Example:**

```
<?
/** Plugin Name: (WPSE) #6345 Example MetaBox plugin */
add_filter( 'plugins_loaded', function() {
    register_post_type( 'book', [
        'register_meta_box_cb' => function() {
            printf(
                '<label>Length:</label>'
                .'<input name="book-length" value="%s" />',
                get_post_custom( get_the_ID() )['book-length'][0]
            );
        },
        # Other arguments
    ] );
}
```

Comment: Would you also use the `add_meta_boxes` hook? I'm a little confused could you add an example please?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Just saw your reply (a little late). Are you still confused?

Comment: @kaiser I'm still confused, could you add an example to your answer please?

Comment: @kaiser - seconded- if you have a moment to add an example it would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @rob-gordon see edit for a small example plugin. Should work.